# KeyError: 'chris' - what is the problem actually?

Tags: python-3.x, oop

The problem is about to print the report of users and their current status of the employees doing login or logout in several machines of a company.

> ```
> class Event:
>   def __init__(self, event_date, event_type, machine_name, user):
>     self.date = event_date
>     self.type = event_type
>     self.machine = machine_name
>     self.user = user
> def get_event_date(event):
>   return event.date
>
> def current_users(events):
>   events.sort(key=get_event_date)
>   machines = {}
>   for event in events:
>     if event.machine not in machines:
>       machines[event.machine] = set()
>     if event.type == "login":
>       machines[event.machine].add(event.user)
>     elif event.type == "logout":
>       machines[event.machine].remove(event.user)
>   return machines
>
> def generate_report(machines):
>   for machine, users in machines.items():
>     if len(users) > 0:
>       user_list = ", ".join(users)
>       print("{}: {}".format(machine, user_list))
>
> events = [
>     Event('2020-01-21 12:45:56', 'login', 'myworkstation.local', 'jordan'),
>     Event('2020-01-22 15:53:42', 'logout', 'webserver.local', 'jordan'),
>     Event('2020-01-21 18:53:21', 'login', 'webserver.local', 'lane'),
>     Event('2020-01-22 10:25:34', 'logout', 'myworkstation.local', 'jordan'),
>     Event('2020-01-21 08:20:01', 'login', 'webserver.local', 'jordan'),
>     Event('2020-01-23 11:24:35', 'logout', 'mailserver.local', 'chris'),
> ]
>
> users = current_users(events)
> print(users)
> ```

I have successfully compiled and got the output on my **pycharm** :

```
{'webserver.local': {'jordan'}}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But I got an error on **jupyter notebook.**

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-46e68509ab0d> in <module>
----> 1 users = current_users(events)
      2 print(users)

<ipython-input-8-5fb178c90d75> in current_users(events)
     11       machines[event.machine].add(event.user)
     12     elif event.type == "logout":
---> 13       machines[event.machine].remove(event.user)
     14   return machines
     15 

KeyError: 'chris'
```

I know it's because we have a user in our events list that was logged out of a machine he was not logged into.

> But my question is, what does such 'chris' keyerror means or why my
> **pycharm** compiled showing the result where **jupyter notebook** did not?

Comment: I am getting same error in pycharm. Are you sure `events` list are same in both pycharm and jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, for user `chris` there is no entry for `login`. So, in `current_users()` function when it encounters the entry for `chris`, it is trying to remove that element from the set.

But the `machines['mailserver.local']` do not have an entry for `chris` in that set. As there is no such entry, you get the mentioned error.

One simple solution is to check if the entry is present in the set before trying to remove it. Like -

```
elif event.type == "logout" and event.user in machines[event.machine]:
    machines[event.machine].remove(event.user)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, 'chris' logged out but has never logged in.

`remove` fails if that key is not found.

You should check if the user is contained in `machines[event.machine]` before removing it.

```
if event.user in machines[event.machine]:
    machines[event.machine].remove(event.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

chris is logout out without a login , you should add a condition to check the user if he logout and his name is in the machines[event.users]

```
elif event.type == "logout" and event.user in machines[event.machine] :
  machines[event.machine].remove(event.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `current_user` function just add a line after your `if` statement

```
elif event.type=="logout" and event.user not in machines[event.machine]:
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

```
elif event.type == "logout":
    for login_event in events:
        if (login_event.user == event.user) and (login_event.type == "login") and (login_event.date < event.date) and (login_event.machine == event.machine):
            machines[event.machine].remove(event.user)
```

I added more checks just in case.